# creating an activity as a system overlay window in which buttons and other elements work

Tags: android-activity, layout, overlay

I am now trying for some time to make a application wherein activities are overlayed on the screen (when the home button is pressed). These activies still need to function instead of only being a view.

For example there is a button in this activity that starts the camera. Normally it works but when the activity is used as overlay the buttons do not work (so I have the idea that only the view is active).

Thanks in advance :)

```
ManageActivity:

private static final String TAG = "CallCamera";
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ = 0;
Uri fileUri = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage);

    Button callCameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cameraButton);
    callCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = getOutputPhotoFile();
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputPhotoFile());
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ);
        }
    });

    Button invite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.inviteButton);
    invite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggleService();

        }
    });
}


public void endEvent(View view) {

    super.finish();

}

private File getOutputPhotoFile() {
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getPackageName());
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create storage directory.");
            return null;
        }
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    return new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"
            + timeStamp + ".jpg");
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri photoUri = null;
            if (data == null) {
                // A known bug here! The image should have saved in fileUri
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                photoUri = fileUri;
            } else {
                photoUri = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully in: " + data.getData(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            // showPhoto(photoUri);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Callout for image capture failed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private void toggleService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OverlayService.class);
    // Try to stop the service if it is already running
    // Otherwise start the service
    if (!stopService(intent)) {
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

}

OverlayService:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent i) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate( ) {
    super.onCreate();



    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,

            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup oView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_manage, null);
    wm.addView(oView, params);


}
```

}

I already have user permission and used the OverlayService as service in manifest